# Laravel 5.6.8 Eloquent and many to many + many to one joins

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have many to many connect with between user - cityarea.
I have also area which connect cityarea (One cityarea can connect only one area).

I have this database structure:

**users**

- id
- username
- password

**cityareas**

- id
- name
- area_id

**cityarea_user**

- id
- cityarea_id
- user_id

**areas**

- id
- name

Next I have Models

**User**

```
public function cityareas()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cityarea');
}
```

**Cityarea**

```
public function area()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Area');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User');
}
```

**Area**

```
public function cityareas()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Cityarea');
}
```

**QUESTION:**

How I can get all users where `areas.name = "South"` with Eloquent ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Jeune Guerrier** solution is perfect, but you can use `with()` method of eloquent If you also need `cityarea` collection along with users collection.

```
$users = User::with('cityareas')->whereHas('cityareas.area', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'South');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks this works great!

Now I have with User model this function

/*
     * Check cityarea
     */
    public function hasCityarea($cityarea)
    {
        return null !== $this->cityareas()->where('name', $area)->first();
    }

With work great.

How can got  area check with user model?
 /*
     * Check one area
     */
    public function hasArea($area)
    {

    }

Answer (score 2):

By using [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations), you can do:

```
$users = User::whereHas('cityareas.area', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'South');
})->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is exactly what the [belongs to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationships is built for.

You simply have to do, `Cityarea::where('name', 'South')->first()->users`;

If you want to do something further with the query, e.g. sort by users created at, you can do

```
Cityarea::where('name', 'South')->first()->users()->orderBy('creaated_at', desc')->get();
```

Note that if there is no such Cityarea with name 'South', the `->first()` query above will return null and therefore will fail to fetch the users.

A more performant way to do it programmatically is to use the `whereHas` approach as discussed in the comments below.

Comment: You do a query, get the results, then load a new query to get the users. This causes a lot of overhead. Use whereHas to run it all in one query.

Comment: I guess you mean 'This causes an overhead'. The user is not asking for best performance either.

Comment: Also, what happens when `CityArea` returns `null` on `first()`? got a nice null pointer waiting there.